# Aptana: Secure FTP in cygwin window

Tags: cygwin, aptana

I am running Aptana 3 to develop web applications.
In the bottom of the IDE there is a panel with the
Cygwin interface to the filesystem including Unix
commands running on top of windows. This is useful
because it means I can use ftp to upload my web
files to the remote server.

However the sftp client (FTP + TLS) is not included
in this distribution. Anyone know an easy way to
add it to this aptana cygwin plugin environment?

Thank you for your help,

John Goche

Answer (score 0):

SFTP is a part of the openssh package. See this answer [on superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/376819/sftp-client-with-cygwin-is-it-possible) for more details.